# PdfWriter (itexpdf) наложение текста строк

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Для создания PDF использую iTextPDF. При создании длинной строки происходит наложение строк друг на друга.
Как это исправить?

```
           final String FONT = "fonts/segoeuisl.ttf";
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("iTextHelloWorld.pdf"));
        document.open();
        BaseFont bf=BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Font font = new Font (bf,14,Font.NORMAL);
        Chunk chunk = new Chunk(GetDn.displayName + "jsdgfjsdgfjkgsdkjfgkjafgjsdgf7239tf2fbjlsgfsdjgfskjdfakjsdg7sf9sdft9gABFLJGJSDJFG67TSD SDFJSDJFKGSDKJFG", font);
        document.add(chunk);
        document.close();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-умолчанию высота строки 0. настройка производится параметром `chunk.setLineHeight(15);`
Код должен выглядеть так:

```
final String FONT = "fonts/segoeuisl.ttf";
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("iTextHelloWorld.pdf"));
        document.open();
        BaseFont bf=BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Font font = new Font (bf,14,Font.NORMAL);
        Chunk chunk = new Chunk(GetDn.displayName + "jsdgfjsdgfjkgsdkjfgkjafgjsdgf7239tf2fbjlsgfsdjgfskjdfakjsdg7sf9sdft9gABFLJGJSDJFG67TSD SDFJSDJFKGSDKJFG", font);
chunk.setLineHeight(15);
        document.add(chunk);
        document.close();
```